# Apache Camel multiple consumers

Tags: ftp, apache-camel

I've been working with Apache Camel for a while and doing some basic stuff, but now I'm trying to create a route in which I can have multiple "consumers" to the same route, or add a consumer to the route and then process the message.

My idea is to have an Event Driven Consumer which is triggered by an event, and then to read a file from an ftp for example. I was planning to do something like this:

```
from("direct:processFile")
  .from("ftp://localhost:21/folder?fileName=${body.fileName}") // etc.
  .log("Start downloading file ${file:name}.")
  .unmarshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, MyFile.class)
  .to("bean:fileProcessor")
  .log("Downloaded file ${file:name} complete.");
```

So the idea is I have an event (for example a direct or from a message queue) that has a "*fileName*" property, and then use the property to download/consume a file with that name from a ftp.

I believe the problem is to have **from().from()** in the same route, but the problem is if I leave the ftp component inside a "to", then my queue event will be written into a file in the ftp, which is the opposite from what I want; it behaves as a produces instead of a consumer.

Is there any possible way to achieve what I'm trying to do or does it conflict with what Camel is for?

Comment: why cant you just add a bean processor after first from and then extract filename and add it as a property to the body and sent it back

Comment: Not sure if I understand, "sent it back" to who? To the camel route? Then the problem is the same, how to consume from the ftp

Comment: Look at the Content Enricher EIP and the pollEnrich

Comment: I would look at SEDA queues. Using a multiple consumer pattern is easy. Read the file in a from send it to a seda in a to and then processs file in SEDA,

Comment: @ClausIbsen Thanks for your help! I was able to make it work with the content enrichers, it's exactly what I was looking for but didn't know the name. I'll post the final solution as a separate answer in case anyone else have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the [comment from Claus Ibsen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439220/apache-camel-multiple-consumers#comment81837579_47439220) I found what I was looking for, the component I needed and wich made it work was the [Content Enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html).

Here is the route that worked for me:

```
from("direct:processFile")
  .pollEnrich().simple("ftp://localhost:21/folder?fileName=${body.fileName}")
  .log("Start downloading file ${file:name}.")
  .unmarshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, MyFile.class)
  .to("bean:fileProcessor")
  .log("Downloaded file ${file:name} complete.");
```

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this ?

```
  .from("direct:processFile")
  .transform(simple("${body.fileName}"))
  .from("ftp://localhost:21/folder?fileName=${body.fileName}") // etc.
  .log("Start downloading file ${file:name}.")
  .unmarshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, MyFile.class)
  .to("bean:fileProcessor")
  .log("Downloaded file ${file:name} complete.");
```

Comment: This is basically the same problem, I'm extracting the file name to another exchange message but the ftp keeps behaving as a producer, writting the file